# Neither the property ... nor one of the methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Two entities with a onetoone relation
First one is a table
Second one is a view

**Nuclei**

```
/**
 * Nuclei
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="datinuclei")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\NucleiRepository")
 */
class Nuclei
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var NucleiStatistiche
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="NucleiStatistiche", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $statistiche;
```

**NucleiStatistiche**

```
/**
 * NucleiStatistiche
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="nuclei_001")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class NucleiStatistiche
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totale_conferimenti", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $totale_conferimenti;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totale_indifferenziata", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $totale_indifferenziata;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="percentuale_indifferenziata", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $percentuale_indifferenziata;


    public function getTotaleConferimenti(): ?string
    {
        return $this->totale_conferimenti;
    }

    public function getTotaleIndifferenziata(): ?string
    {
        return $this->totale_indifferenziata;
    }

    public function getPercentualeIndifferenziata(): ?string
    {
        return $this->percentuale_indifferenziata;
    }
```

Test it on a controller using

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Nuclei::class)->findBy(
        array('comune' => $this->id_comune, 'id' => '14523')
    );

{% for nucleo in nuclei %}
    {{ dump(nucleo.statistiche) }}
{% endfor %}

App\Entity\NucleiStatistiche {#925 ▼
  -id: 14523
  -totale_conferimenti: 107
  -totale_indifferenziata: 2
  -percentuale_indifferenziata: 2
}
```

I can see values using dump, but when refer to a property into twig i recive an error

```
{% for nucleo in nuclei %}
    {{ dump(nucleo.statistiche.totale_conferimenti) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Neither the property `totale_conferimenti` nor one of the methods `totale_conferimenti()`,
`gettotale_conferimenti()`/`istotale_conferimenti()`/`hastotale_conferimenti()` or `__call()` exist
and have public access in class `App\Entity\NucleiStatistiche`.

I don't understand what the solution is... crazy!!!

Comment: Try with camel case nucleo.statistiche.totaleConferimenti

Comment: Omg.. thanks this solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axiom: Everything is difficult until you understand it.

Our first need is to understand how this works. In PHP, `private`/`protected` means they will not be available outside the object's scope. Twig tries to access them from outside the object scope, which causes the problem.

In other words: What your Twig attempts to use is not available to it.

Yet, I'm sure you have seen Twig seemingly using `private`/`protected` members, so your empiric evidence seemingly contradicts to the theory I have outlined. But only seemingly. You understand what the problem is, but at this point you don't yet understand how those keywords can be used.

The [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) is clear about it, when it explains that when foo.bar is being used, if bar is not a member of foo, then it eventually checks for foo.getBar(), a getter. So, you will need to implement `getStatistiche` and operate similarly for its members. I did not use Twig for a while, but if memory serves me well, for `totale_conferimenti` you will need `getTotaleConferimenti`.

EDIT (Jakumi's helpful comment):

you're about 90% right. Symfony usually assumes camel case and in that case your assumed getter name would be correct. the error message states the expected getter name though. also additional handy information: dump's output has a - prepended to every private/inaccessible property and + prepended for every public property. The diagnosis however is a 100% correct, missing getter for an "inaccessible" property and no possible fallback.

Comment: you're about 90% right. Symfony usually assumes camel case and in that case your assumed getter name would be correct. the error message states the expected getter name though. also additional handy information: `dump`'s output has a `-` prepended to every private/inaccessible property and `+` prepended for every public property. The diagnosis however is a 100% correct, missing getter for an "inaccessible" property and no possible fallback.